# Display latest post if custom fields are true

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, field

I am trying to get a wordpress to post a latest post only if three conditions are met using custom fields. First the river has to be the 'Colorado', Area has to be 'Area 4' and position has to be 'soundbite 5'. Is this even possible to do?

Code so far:

```
<?php $querystr = "
      SELECT wposts.*
      FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
      WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
      AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'select_river'
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Colorado'
      AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'select_area'
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Area 4'
      AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'select_soundbite_position'
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'soundbite 5'
      AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
      AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
      ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
      ";

     $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

      if ($pageposts):
      foreach ($pageposts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post); ?>

        <p>Test</p>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

It doesn't work and I have no idea why... well my understanding of PHP is lacking

Answer (score 0):

What about that:

```
<?php
$querystr = "
      SELECT wposts.*
      FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta3
      WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
      AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'select_river'
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Colorado'
      AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'select_area'
      AND wpostmeta2.meta_value = 'Area 4'
      AND wpostmeta3.meta_key = 'select_soundbite_position'
      AND wpostmeta3.meta_value = 'soundbite 5'
      AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
      AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
      ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
      ";
?>
```